# Как добавить закреплённые кнопки в telegram.bot на С#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Хочу сделать telegram бота на C# через библиотеку telegram.bot, но никак не могу найти способ добавить закреплённые кнопки снизу и действие которое будет совершаться после их нажатие. Пробовал искать разные способы в по всему инету, но ничего не помогло.. Может я не подключил нужный элемент библиотеки telegram.bot
Подскажите люди добрые, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Start ()
    {
        var bot = new TelegramBotClient("Токен твоего бота"); //авторизуем бота
        bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage; //Создаем событие, программа сообщит тебе о сообщении в методе Bot_OnMessage.
        bot.StartReceiving(); //Начинаем принимать сообещния.
        Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue);
    }

    private static void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        var message = e.Message.Text; //тут сообщение, которое написал пользователь
        Console.WriteLine(message); //Выводим его в консоль.
    }
```

Выше я привел банальный пример кода бота. во входном методе (void Main) прописываешь Start();  и он запустится. Написав сообщение боту в телеграмм в консоле появится твое сообщение.